# Finding all numbers [c] guaranteed by the Mean Value Theorem?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

Can someone help explain how to use the Mean Value Theorem to me? I've been Googling for the last  30 minutes and still not getting anywhere. My example problem is as follows:

Find all the numbers *c*  guaranteed by the Mean Value THeorem for $f(x)=\dfrac13 (x^3+x-4)$ on the  interval $[-1,2]$.

So far from what I've put together, my function in this case is Continuous (no breaks in the line of the graph on my calculator) and the derivative $f'(x)$ of my function is  = $(3x^2+1)/(3)$.

What do I do now / how do I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track.  Now you just solve for values of $c$ such that

$f^\prime(c) = \frac{f(2) - f(-1)}{2 - (-1)}$ and I will leave this task for you to do.

Comment: Mustafa, I appreciate your faith in me, but I'm asking for help because I'm well and truly lost. Does your post indicate I should take the solution of plugging in 2 to my function, subtracting the solution of plugging 1 into my function, and then divide the total of that by 2-(-1)? If so, where in the world/how did you get that denominator?